# How to push image to Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I can't push my local image to Docker hub. I checked every topics in here but still couldn't solve it.

My local image is like below;

```
[root@DOCKER2Demo]# docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
companyrepo123/man-demo        latest                b86sbfd26        41 minutes ago      5.31GB
```

So I want to push this image to the "companyrepo123/man-demo:latest" repository.

So I login successfully with "docker login" and run the command below

```
docker push companyrepo123/man-demo:latest
```

But gives the error below;

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/companyrepo123/man-demo]
82bb2b81506d: Preparing
0ae79b7db02c: Preparing
df9824e71502: Preparing
d384c5326457: Preparing
da1504cd9d9b: Preparing
976e766378b6: Waiting
8154f91c38f9: Waiting
a74cf09880c3: Waiting
1c0efef42405: Waiting
1417e6a7c4fd: Waiting
79ac04ef09ff: Waiting
77b174a6a187: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I already login. Tried to logout and login and but still same.

**Please noticed that my username is not "companyrepo123". This is our company's repository, my username to login Docker hub is "yatta".**

How can I push that image?

Regards.

Comment: have you created the docker repository named `myrepo123` in docker hub? see the [creating repositories](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#creating-repositories) section in docs for details if not done already.

Comment: Yes, it's exist, of course not exact name but it's exist. I tried with exactly same name, but still fails.

Comment: after reading the question again, I realized that the problem may be access related based on the message: `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`..not entirely sure if it is relevant but you could have a look at [service account](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#service-accounts) section as well.

Comment: Thanks but still couldn't figured out how to solve. That operation should be pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push to a repository under your namespace in Docker Hub, where the first part of that path is your username or organization. So `myrepo123` would be your username.

Next, you'll want to create the repository, `myrepo123/man-demo` on Docker Hub (from the web interface), and if this is under an organization, make sure your user has access to push to that repo within the organization.

If you've done that, then make sure you have logged into Docker Hub, with the correct username, using:

```
docker login
```

If you have enabled 2fa on Hub, the password for this is an access token you generate from the web page.

Comment: Actually my username is different than "myrepo123". "myrepo123" is my company's name/repository and I login to that repository with my "yatta" username.

Comment: @yatta are you a member of that organization, with access to push. Please verify you have gone through the various steps of the above answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm am member as "owner".